# How to develop skype calling functionality using Azure Bot Service

Tags: bots, skype, botframework, botconnector, azure-bot-service

I am working on Bot technology, I had developed one simple skype bot with skype calling feature using calling controller template through this below link.

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/calling.html

Before posted question here I read the below documentation about azure bot service.

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/#navtitle

In the above link, all samples are related to only Messages but I want the Skype calling functionality using azure bot service.

Can you please tell me how to develop on simple bot with skype calling functionality using azure bot service concept?

-Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-audio-calls) for voice calling using the Azure Bot Framework.  It states:

> If you are building a bot for Skype, your bot can communicate with
>   users via audio call. Audio calls are useful when the user does not
>   want to or cannot provide input by typing, tapping, or clicking. A bot
>   may support other user controls such as rich cards or text in addition
>   to audio calls, or communicate through audio calls only.

This involves instantiating a `CallingController` which then registers an event for `ProcessIncomingCallAsync`.  Once you have answered the call using this method you can do things like play an audio file over the call, record what the caller says, or capture dialpad number entry.